# Keras: confusion matrix versus accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras

- The accuracy vs epoch show about 70% for the last epoch for the test dataset (see 1), while the confusion matrix for this same dataset show normalized value below 0.5 (see 2) on the accuracy diagonal.
- I would expect these values to be consistent with the accuracy, so around 0.7, am I wrong?

(1)

[image]

(2)

[image]

Comment: Try "categorical_accuracy". Or train with "categorical_crossentropy" loss. Or use only one element for output instead of 2.

Comment: Can you also provide how you defined your accuracy and confusion matrix? For sure, they need to be the same.

Comment: Can you please tell about the size of the data set and the size of data considered for Training, testing n validation(if considered).

Comment: - to compile I used: loss = 'binary_crossentropy' and metrics=['accuracy'].       - for the confusion matrix I used: cm = confusion_matrix(label_test, pred_data_test) and plot_confusion_matrix (cm, label) as recommended by keras.

Comment: 1 image has  about (1500*500) pixels. I used 5000 images to train and 5000 to test.

Comment: Concerning Daniel comments, even if I'm not using optimal parameters, I should still have consistent results, right?